# How to set the trust level for processor ID in .net window application?

Tags: c#, permissions, processor, code-access-security, full-trust

I developing window application in C#. I created one installer with this windows application. It is running fine on nearly all computers. The window application takes the ID of processor & then based on that ID generates one unique key. On one computer it is giving the error "Windows installer failed to generate the key. Please contact your administrator". I have debugged the .net code & found that it is not having the proper permissions to access the processor ID. What should I need to do ? How should I set the trust level in .net (window application ) to access the processor ID of the particular computer ?. Can you please provide me any code or link or any procedure through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the processor Id can be turned off in the bios, did you check that the machine actually has a processor Id?